# encryptData GlobalPlatform

Tags: encryption, javacard

I'm sending an APDU without CMAC (CLA byte = `0x80`) to an applet. I'm using SCP02 i55. I need encrypt data with the `SecureChannel.encryptData()` function. I don't want to encrypt it manually, I need that Global Platform encrypts data and after I will decrypt it with the correct session key (I'm sure that they are well calculated).

I'm using the following code to encrypt the APDU buffer.

```
byte buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
buffer[0] = 20;
short lc = chan.encryptData(buffer, (short) 0, (short) 1);
apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, lc);
```

This throws a security status not satisfied exception (`0x6982`) where I expected a response APDU with encrypted 20.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: That is way too little info. Which Secure Messaging protocol are you using? How do you encrypt? Do you calculate the session data encryption key yourself?

Comment: Downvoted as no additional information was returned by bra_racing.

Comment: Sorry for not answer, but I'm on holidays and not have internet access.

I'm using scp02, i = 55

I don't want to encrypt manually, I need that globalplatform encrypts data and after I will decrypt it with the correct session key (I'm sure that they are well calculated)

Thanks a lot

Comment: @martijno ok, I'm going to write an example. I have a main class that sends an APDU to my applet. When the applet receives the APDU it does: `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA] = 20;` `apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) 1);`

Comment: Sorry @martijno, the correctcode is: `byte buffer = apdu.getBuffer();` `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA] = 20;` `short lc = chan.encryptData(buffer, (short) 0, (short) 1);` `apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, lc);` Thanks

Comment: You may want to edit your question, instead of adding code in a comment! Your code doesn't call `setIncoming()` and/or `receiveBytes()`, is this really the _complete_ example? Can you also indicate (by changing your question) how the decrypted data is different from what you expected?

Comment: Sorry for the format I'm using the blackberry and it's imposible to write well, and I can't edit the answer with the phone. It isn't the complete example, but I can't copy all. They are the lines that doesn't work. When I execute this code, I obtein a 6982 answer (security status not satisfied) and I expect the answer (a 20) encrypted. Thanks

Comment: I edited the question, adding your code. SO says it needs peer reviewing before my edits will become visible.

Comment: @martijno wow thank you very much. Now I continue working for discover a solution. Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you delete the code comments from this question? I'll remove this comment, so we have some space to troubleshoot :)

Comment: I presume you did authenticate using the `GPSystem` class before? Did you try to wrap and unwrap the APDU as well? Can you wrap your call to `encryptData` with a try catch and see if an exception is thrown (wrap the result of `getReason()` using `ISO7816Exception.throwIt()`).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap the status bytes. From the standard:

> The applet is responsible for appending the expected status bytes at the end of the response data in order for them to be protected by secure messaging;

Comment: Thanks @owlstead, you're right, but I can't encrypt because my card doesn't support R-ENCRYPTION, and here [link](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/gp211/org/globalplatform/SecureChannel.html#getSecurityLevel()) we can see that it's necesary for use the `encryptData(...)` method.

Comment: Funny that, because I don't think I'm right... I think I confused it with wrap. I also think that your status word is not generated during encrypt call, but I have to look that up. Maybe you need to call wrap method after calling encrypt?

Comment: Did you see the other comment on the question? Note that the authentication to the cardmanager is not enough.